# Translate Postgres query into T-SQL for SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

There are many articles pertaining to "translate SQL Server to Postgres". I have a Postgres query that I would like to translate into SQL Server. Does someone have the answer or at least a website to check?

Thanks,
Frank

While I can appreciate that some people would like to see the query, I would rather learn to do it myself.

Comment: How can anyone answer that if you don't even bother to add the query?

Comment: Postgres query languages is similar to Oracle, so you can to try this way. http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/

Comment: You could enter your query into SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and see what errors it flags.

Comment: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) has tutorials for the SQL syntax with some examples of where it's done differently in the major RDBMS's. And a lot of SQL can be written in a standard way which would run on most recent versions of the databases.